# What to look for in a bicycle meant for the exercise?

Tags: exercise

I do not need the bicycle for daily commuting or mountain climbing.
I need the bicycle for morning and evening exercise and just for roaming around in order to get some fresh air.

I also want a **smooth** ride on non-smooth roads. I am a female.

What to look for in a bicycle meant for the above described needs?
Budget: 103$
Country: India

### ***Update***

I searched for and found the following bicycles with suspensions.
They fall near about $ 103.

1. http://www.choosemybicycle.com/in/en/bicycles/hercules/hybrid-/hercules-atom/Technical-Specifications
2. http://www.choosemybicycle.com/in/en/bicycles/hercules/hybrid-/hercules-rebellio-619/Technical-Specifications
3. http://www.choosemybicycle.com/in/en/bicycles/hero/mtb/hero-ranger-dtb-vx-2013/Technical-Specifications

How do I know whether they are comfortable for exercise and roaming around?

***Regarding exercise:***
I am an underweight female so loosing weight is not my goal.
I wish to get mentally fit and therefore I wish to tire myself out without getting bored. They say physical exercise is necessary to get rid of depression.
Hence I chose to cycle out.

[What to look for in a bicycle meant for the exercise?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/21622/what-to-look-for-in-a-bicycle-meant-for-the-exercise#comment39603_21622)

> The most important thing is that it be the right size for you, and after that you appear to want a "relaxed", upright posture rather than a "racing" posture. For that an inexpensively-built "city bike" (such as Andy's illustration) or perhaps a "hybrid" is probably the best choice.

Are the bikes shown above hybrid?

Comment: will you be wanting to carry baggage?

Comment: @PeteH A water bottle and a camera bag - That's all.

Comment: then I agree with @mattnz about the hybrid bike. And that a visit to a local shop would be worthwhile.

Comment: Start by borrowing a bike or buying an inexpensive used one, to get used to what you want/need.  Just make sure when you test ride it that it's comfortable and seems to fit right.  The most important thing is that it be the right size for you, and after that you appear to want a "relaxed", upright posture rather than a "racing" posture.  For that an inexpensively-built "city bike" (such as Andy's illustration) or perhaps a "hybrid" is probably the best choice.  And get a bike shop to explain proper "bike fit" to you -- mainly how the seat should be adjusted.

Comment: Some have mentioned distance riding but if your goal is weight loss or cardiovascular strength then its very different. You're not going to get any sort of fitness out of a cheap City Bike / Cruiser.

Comment: @Ryan - I disagree.  Any sort of non-impact exercise is good, and you can get quite a bit of exercise riding a bike at a moderate pace through neighborhoods for an hour or so at a time.

Comment: @DanielRHicks City Bike / Cruisers are comfort bikes designed for low pace so I'm really not sure how you disagree with me.

Comment: @Ryan - You can gain considerable fitness at a low pace.

Comment: @DanielRHicks I'm happy to continue this conversation in chat or another question but its really not important here based on TheIndependentAquarius' edit.

Comment: @Ryan Really no fitness from a cruiser. Try holding 12 mph for and hour on a cruiser.

Comment: @Blam sorry that's just not an accurate assessment. If you want to use a screwdriver as a hammer then be my guest but I prefer to use the right tool for the job and encourage others to do the same. Do Cruisers have their place? Yes. Can you force speed into them? Sure. I can also go for a run in a pair of Allen Edmund's shoes. But I don't think anyone on a running site would encourage the comfort of an Allen Edmund's shoe for running despite it being possible. So why are you all so bent on encouraging a comfort bike for fitness here? Its completely illogical.

Comment: **Following the update** No,  they are not hybrids. Each of the bikes shown are mountain bikes with full suspension. While such bikes would probably match your requirements, they probably would not last for long. You get what you pay for and your budget is very limited. If you can locate one, a used bike will give better value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am an underweight female so loosing weight is NOT my goal. I wish to get mentally fit and therefore I wish to tire myself out without getting bored. They say physical exercise is necessary to get rid of depression. Hence I chose to cycle out.

First and most important is the depression. You should really go to a bike shop and hop on a few different bikes and styles. Try them all. The one that makes you feel giddy and excited is the one to get. Pleasure, smiling, laughter, and exercise all release endorphins which help depression. Get the one that will not only give you exercise but also make you feel great! **This is also how you will know if it is comfortable and fits you.**

> wish to get mentally fit and therefore I wish to tire myself out without getting bored

This is best done by picking difficult challenges that you enjoy. It could be getting a BMX bike and working to learn one trick after another. It could be setting a speed goal for yourself that really forces you to push yourself. It could be any number of things. Just set challenging goals and surround yourself with others that will push you to reach them.

> I am an underweight female so loosing weight is NOT my goal.

Eat more. Seriously. Any exercise will cause a little weight loss and if you're really looking to challenge yourself mentally then that means more than a leisure ride. That means more calories. You'll have to learn what the right amount to eat is to not lose weight and then you can decide if you want to eat more to put on weight.

---

**My feeling**

The bike you chose looks odd to me but if it makes you happy it also looks versatile and fun. I could see taking to some trails and little jumps on it. Otherwise the more I write the more I'm inclined to suggest a smaller BMX bike like:

[image]

You can generally find them pretty cheap (not this model but other ones). They're incredibly durable. Relaxing for when you do want those roaming around trips, but can also be pushed for the fitness side. And learning a new trick or jump will burn less calories so you don't lose weight. Loads of fun too!

Comment: Thanks for the response. `The bike you chose looks odd to me` Why? Please explain. I chose that only because it has shockers and is under $103. I don't know whether test drive is allowed for cycles in India.

Comment: your picture is not loading properly.

Comment: I tried a different picture. Let me know if it isn't loading either.

Comment: the picture in the other answer is loading without any probkems, perhaps you have chosen a big size. please reduce your pic size to kbs and then try to include.

Comment: and meanwhile please tell why did you find it odd.

Comment: The bike you chose looks odd because it looks like its trying to do too much and none quite right. Its got the frame of a downhill mountain bike, fenders and rack though like a city bike, and no idea what those vertical handlebars are. It does look like it could be fun if you are intending on going offroad on trails and downhill but otherwise not so much. I suspect its also very heavy. Best I can tell it has no gears so that further makes me believe its best used in downhill freestyle.

Comment: Oh you know what I bet images have to be approved for me on here because I don't have a lot of rep. So probably someone with more rep has to approve it before you can see it. Here's a link in the meantime: http://static.bootic.com/_pictures/1390593/gt-compe-2010.jpg

Comment: the vertical handles are mostly commonly seen here on every stylish bike - they are probably for style. I thought gears are meant for racing and all or mountain climbing? I thought I won't miss the gears because the aim is to get tired. Am I wrong in my interpretation?

Comment: No you're right which is why it looks a bit odd to me. The bike you posted calls itself an entry level mountain bike and has the frame of a downhill freestyle bike but not the gears to match. See that bike you posted is trying to be like this: http://www.gtbicycles.com/usa_en/2014/bikes/mountain/2014-force-carbon-expert but without the gears, plus the added weight from all the fenders and racks, is going to make it excessively heavy in my opinion.

Comment: if no shockers and no gears are now expected in a cheap bike then can I go for this? http://www.choosemybicycle.com/in/en/bicycles/hero/mtb/hero-miss-india-gold-jr-2013/Price-India

Comment: Like I said your original choice looks odd but could be versatile and fun. Test ride and see what you enjoy. There's really not much else I can say, and getting into specific models is frowned upon here. Have fun with whichever bike you go with!

Comment: `getting into specific models is frowned upon here.` Wrong. Suggesting and asking help for specified models is frowned upon here. The reason why I pointed out the other model is that I don't understand the technical differences between the two so I cannot decide. anyways, thanks for your help. won't bother you further now.

Answer (score 4):

Very hard to answer without knowing your budget.

I would suggest a hybrid style bike. They have an upright riding position and geometry designed for comfort over speed (road racer) or agility (MTB). They have largish tires to absorb the minor bumps. Look at a bike with 29" (700C) wheels and at least 1.5" (35mm) tires for the smoother ride you want.

You are looking for a "smooth ride over non-smooth roads" - presumably for comfort - one of the holy grail of cycles. The closest you will get is a high end Cross country Mountain bike with full suspension. However, I would not recommend it (depending on how bumpy you are talking about), as the cost/weight penalty is high, and even the best can only increase comfort so much.

If you are worried about seat comfort, several things can be done. Suspension seat posts an help, but a woman's specific saddle would be my first recommendation. Large, plush saddles can get uncomfortable over longer distances and cause chaffing, so are not always the answer.

I suggest visiting you Local bike shop (LBS) and talking to them.  Stay away from Chains stores if you can afford to.

Re Your Update:
All those bikes look like they will be more trouble than they are worth. The complexity of full suspension combined with a bike in that price bracket is a recipe for a very unpleasant experience. The bike will be heavy and hard to ride, especially with no gears. I would suggest something more like the [Hercules Arrow 6spd](http://www.choosemybicycle.com/in/en/bicycles/hercules/hybrid-/hercules-arrow-6spd/Technical-Specifications)

Comment: `woman's specific saddle` What does that mean?

Comment: @TheIndependentAquarius there are different saddles for men and women.

Comment: A hybrid with front suspension and saddle post "suspension" - usually just a spring - seems like a good idea here.  The hybrid front suspension has a much shorter travel than true MTB suspension.  Has anyone ridden a decent one recently though?

Comment: @ChrisH you could maybe get away without front suspension, after all 35mm tyres can be quite forgiving. But it all depends on how bumpy the op's roads are and what lengths she's prepared to go to to negate those bumps. Ultimately that's why a visit to a shop is a good idea - how "smooth" is "smooth enough"?

Comment: @PeteH I ride on 35s (for now) on a range of roads/paths from very nice tarmac to potholes to good dirt (and mud over tarmac, but that's another story with an uncomfortable ending).  They're smooth enough for me, so long as I stand on the pedals over the worst bits, but I'm reasonably heavy and run the tyres at ~65psi (their max).  I agree with you completely I think - instead of / as well as the LBS, any local cycling groups (especially work/commuting-related as they tends to be about gentler riding) would be good for a chat.

Comment: @ChrisH Please see the edited question.

Comment: mattnz: the bike you suggested has no shockers. If no shockers is the way to go then a simple ladies bike will also be okay. Am I wrong? http://www.choosemybicycle.com/in/en/bicycles/hero/mtb/hero-miss-india-gold-jr-2013/Price-India

Answer (score 1):

In your question you say nothing about your fitness level, or expected riding speeds / distances.

If you are reasonably fit, and want to ride, say 10km in half an hour (20kph), then I would certainly agree with [mattnz's answer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/21623/8273).

But when you say *just for roaming around*, I hear requirements more like those of my wife:

[image]

In many places, this is called a Dutch Bike, or City Bike. Some people just call them ladies shopping bikes.

Under the (ladies) seat there are springs to cushion your ride. In the picture the seat is unusually low; normally it would be at least 10cm higher.

The main concern I have with your requirements is your budget. While I know nothing of prices in India, I suspect that you will need to aim for a second hand bike. As others have said, do go your LBS to see what your possibilities are.

Comment: A dutchie was my first thought when I asked above about luggage. I have one of these and love it (for the right purpose). Plus, if fitness is your goal, what better than riding a 20kg bike? But I'd just question how long you could ride a dutchie for before it would become uncomfortable? My ballpark guess (based on mine) would only be an hour or so.

Comment: @PeteH Yes, it depends what the OP means by fitness. For me, a (distant) goal is to be able to climb 1000m per day. For my wife, it's to be able to ride to the shops 5km away.

Comment: Yes shops is what I use mine for - I had no other bike that could reasonably carry shopping and it seemed daft to be cycling 100km a week, but jumping in the car to go get a pint of milk. I think the longest I ever rode it was to the nearest town, accompanying my wife on her hybrid. My ability is that much greater than hers, so me riding the granny bike made us just about even!

Comment: @PeteH Please see the edited question.